# filling lists while running a for loop without creating new lists

Tags: r, list, for-loop

Say I have several datasets and I want to run the same analysis for all of them, and store the results in a list. Should I make an empty list or an empty vector before running the analysis, or can I just do it while running the loop?

For example, I have `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`, and I want to run the `MYFUN` function, and store the result dataframes into `MYRES`, something like this:

```
testlist = list(df1,df2,df3)
for(i in 1:length(testlist)){
  MYRES[[i]] = MYFUN(testlist[[i]]) 
}
```

This code says `Error: object 'tstscrs' not found`. I have no problem in creating empty lists before running the loop, my question is there a way to do it without that, because the analysis is much longer than this, I'll have to create about 20 empty lists and vectors, perhaps there is a way to avoid that?

Comment: You can use `lapply` instead. `MYRES <- lapply(testlist, MYFUN)`

Comment: @AllanCameron awesome tip, however this does not solve it, I think. For example I have this line: `INDEX = intersect(rownames(rawlist[i]), gene_length[[i]]$ensembl_gene_id)` inside the for loop, can `lapply` also get this done?

Comment: I don't think you are providing enough information here for us to address your issues.
initialize a list before the for loop like `MYRES <- vector("list", length(testlist))`